# Jquery event not working after append html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have ajax request and when the ajax success I'm replacing the content using html from the ajax response.

The controller is like this:

```
$html = view('payroll-cutoff.data-attendance-group', compact('payroll_group', 'payroll_cutoff_group'))->render();
return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'data' => $html,
]);
```

Inside ajax success, I have some code to manipulate the view. But somehow after I successfully replacing the html content of `tbody`, the jquery event not working anymore even though when I inspect the element I successfully replacing the content using html from ajax response.

```
 success:function(response){
         // thisObj = '.process-attendance'
         let element = response.data;
         let el_data = $(element).filter('.group-payroll').find('.body-component').html();
         thisObj.closest('table').find('tbody').html(el_data);

         // code bellow not working
         thisObj.closest('table').find('thead').addClass('done-group');
         thisObj.closest('table').find('tbody').addClass('done-group');
        },
```

For example is I have this on click function, but it's not working anymore after ajax success.

```
$(".show-emp").click(function () {
   showEmployee($(this));
});

function showEmployee(el)
{
    $(el).closest('tbody').find('.employee').toggle();
    $(el).closest('tbody').find('.employee-head').toggle();
}
```

And this is the view:

```
<table class="table group-payroll">
    <thead class="head-component">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="body-component">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%" colspan="7">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm mb-2 checkall process-attendance">Process Attendance</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm mb-2 checkall me-5 show-emp"></a>5 Employee
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="employee-head" style="display: none">
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>HK</td>
            <td>IN</td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" class="process-done" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="employee_id[]" class="employee_id" value="">
        <tr class="employee" style="display: none">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if the below's code work

```
$(".group-payroll").on('click', '.show-emp', function () {
   showEmployee($(this));
});
```

Check out the [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data). There are two types of event handlers, direct and delegated. This is a delegated event handler.

Delegated event handlers have the advantage that they can process events from **descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time**.

in your case that HTML added to the table after success is *descendent elements*.

Comment: Thanks, this code working. But I don't know why, also I don't have any idea how to make the adding class code inside ajax success working

Comment: Check out the jquery documentation. There are two types of event handler, direct and delegated. This is a delegated event handler.

Delegated event handlers have the advantage 'that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.'

Comment: @Catto I edited my answer regarding how the code works.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the difference between direct & delegated. But in my case, which event should I use and did I have to move the addClass code outside of ajax success? I'm a little confused because I can have more than 1 table on the same page, if I use class name then all table class on the page is changed. I only want to add the class to specific table (which is the table from ajax success)

Comment: @Catto You need to create dynamic ID or class with help of loop and play with them. or you can also achieve with `data-*` attribute. like you can create dynamic id="emp1" then pass id value inside `data-getid="emp1"` and show/hide according of multiple table.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam the toggle event already working, only add class still not working `thisObj.closest('table').find('thead').addClass('done-group');`

Comment: @Catto Have you tried with `setTimeout(()=> {  your code  },1000 )` method?

Comment: @Catto, just use the parent class as a delegated event class. Suppose all your table (you mentioned more than one) is wrapped by a div class called 'all-tables', instead of 'group-payroll' use 'all-tables'. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try like below snippet.

*Helpful Links*:
https://api.jquery.com/on/
https://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$(document).on("click", ".show-emp", function () {   
  showEmployee($(this));<br> 
});
```

Comment: thanks, but how to make the adding class code inside ajax success working?

Comment: Toggling will not work because of your html format is not correct `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm mb-2 checkall me-5 show-emp"></a>5 Employee ` this should be like **`<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm mb-2 checkall me-5 show-emp">5 Employee</a>`** then click event will work(fire).

Comment: @Catto `5 Employee` text should be wrap by `<a>` tag so text should not be outside of `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, the `<a>` tag is only a toggle button & I'm styling it using css. And the `5 Employee` text is inside `<td>`